# How to indicate browser to move more than 1 level up ?

Tags: html

Since using " ../ " before  a filename indicates that the browser should move up 1 level in the directory structure, is there a way to indicate to the browser to move more than 1 level up ?

Comment: Use your imagination a bit, and try stuff out.

Comment: Gee thanks for the replies.. Somehow I didn't think of adding another "../" . I was fiddling with "../2" and something else..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think very simple unless i don't understand the problem

add ../ for every level like this

2 level

```
../../folder_file
```

3 level

```
../../../folder_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Guess I failed big time =/.

Answer (score 1):

It will go up another level by adding another `../`

```
../../script.js
```